# Python Subprocess.run with integer input

Tags: python, input, subprocess

I am a python beginner and practice control files.

I created a simple first python file like this:

```
l1 = ['Bob', 'Eric', 'Dimitar', 'Kyle']
n = input('Enter no. of persons:  ')
print(l1[int(n)])
```

I run this file from another python file like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("python random.py", shell=True  )
```

This works, but it runs the first python file without prompting for input. Is there any way I can send "n" from the second script as input to the first script?

Something similar to this:

```
subprocess.run("python random.py", shell=True ,**input(n) = 2** )
```

Comment: "subprocess.run" has a parameter "input". If you set it to a string or byte sequence, it will be sent as input to the called process (should end with a `\n` to simulate press of "Return").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With subprocess, you can't control which variable to place the input into (assuming this was your intention with `input(n) = 2`), but you can control the input to the subprocess itself. For example, `runner.py` file:

```
import subprocess

inp = b'2'
subprocess.run("python random.py", shell=True, input=inp)
```

Then running it would result in:

```
$ python runner.py
Enter no. of persons:  Dimitar
```

Note that the input has to be of type `bytes`, or specify encoding. Also, pay attention to newlines (this example requires only a single input).
Read more about the `run()` method in Python's documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).